# multiple async-await get requests not working in PERN stack app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, async-await, fetch

I'm working on building an inventory management application using PERN stack. I have a modal where I need to make 2 GET requests and when I console.log in front end both requests are getting Status 200 response. However in my express server, first get request is working fine but the second request is not receiving anything.

My frontend code

```
const openModal = async () => {
        setDetailModalOpen(true)
        try {
            await Promise.all([
                (async () => {
                    const serial_number = props.bacsSerial
                    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/bacslist/demoinventory/${serial_number}`)
                    const parseResponse = await response.json()
                    console.log(response)
                    setInputs({
                        bacsUnit: parseResponse.bacs_unit,
                        serialNumber: parseResponse.serial_number,
                        partNumber: parseResponse.part_number,
                        bacsLocation: parseResponse.bacs_location,
                        description: parseResponse.bacs_description
                    })
                    setBacsId(parseResponse.id)
                    setBacsData(parseResponse)
                })(),
                (async () => {
                    const response2 = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/bacslist/demoinventory/${bacsId}`)
                    console.log(response2)
                })()
            ])
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
        }
    }
```

My backend code

```
router.get("/demoinventory/:serial_number", async (req, res) => {
    console.log('This one is working')
    try {
        const {serial_number} = req.params
        const getDemoBacs = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM demo_inventory WHERE serial_number = $1", [serial_number]
        )
        
        res.json(getDemoBacs.rows[0])
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
})

router.get("/demoinventory/:bacsId", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params)
    console.log('This one is not working')
    try {
        const getHistoryData = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM demo_inventory_history"
        )
        console.log(getHistoryData)
        res.json(getHistoryData)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Kinda new to this stuff so this isn't exactly an answer but I'm not allowed to leave a comment. I can't see your state variables with the code you posted, but are you sure that `BacsId` is being set to state before it is used in the second call, or is the parameter in the second call being sent empty, thus not using the right URL? Just a thought.

Comment: Yes. bacsId state is being set and I could console.log it. Now I found that if I use a completely different URL, which doesn't even exist, it still returns 200...

Comment: I fixed it. There was a problem with my 2nd request URL.